# Solr - subqueries

Tags: join, solr, subquery

I need to do a Solr sub-query, which if it was in MySQL would look like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM solr_index
WHERE type = 'person' AND 
city IN (SELECT name FROM solr_index WHERE name = 'London' AND type = 'city')
```

Apparently Solr Joins are very similar - http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Join. But these are only available in Solr 4 it seems. Is there some way I can do this in Solr 3.X ?

Ideally a way compatible with the ComplexPhraseQueryParser and that the Solr PHP Client or Solarium have support for.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

Another example which is not location related:

```
SELECT *
FROM solr_index
WHERE type = 'project' AND 
tag IN (SELECT name FROM solr_index WHERE name = 'Elephant' AND type = 'tag')
```

Comment: Probably better off looking into the geo / spatial features instead of string based searching of location information. http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpatialSearch

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I need this functionality for a few scenarios - not just related to location. I've added another example to demonstrate how I would use it for something else.

Comment: People usually denormalize (flatten) their schema in order not to have to do joins. Isn't it possible in your case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

joins are there since solr 3.4. Check this out

http://lucidworks.com/blog/lucene_3_4_0/

Comment: @pashgolpashgolian thanks for pointing, fixed. Apparently Lucidworks have updated their blog, but have not setup link redirects.

Answer (score 1):

I would try different variants of filter queries and facets. Something like:

```
q=*:*
fq=(type:city AND name:london)
facet=true
facet.query=type:person
```

Hope this helps and best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
q=*:*&fq=city:london&fq=type:(city OR person)
```